# Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to map my enum values in my postgres database using the example in this link https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-enum-mappings/  using converter to persist the values of the enum,

but I keep getting this error

***my enum***

```
public enum Rating {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE
}
```

***the converter***

```
@Converter
public class RatingAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Rating, Integer> {
 
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Rating attribute) {
        if (attribute == null)
            return null;
 
        switch (attribute) {
        case ONE:
            return 1;
 
        case TWO:
            return 2;
 
        case THREE:
            return 3;
 
        case FOUR:
            return 4;
 
        case FIVE:
            return 5;
 
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(attribute + " not supported.");
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public Rating convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        if (dbData == null)
            return null;
 
        switch (dbData) {
        case 1:
            return Rating.ONE;
 
        case 2:
            return Rating.TWO;
 
        case 3:
            return Rating.THREE;
 
        case 4:
            return Rating.FOUR;
 
        case 5:
            return Rating.FIVE;
 
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(dbData + " not supported.");
        }
    }
 
}
```

***my class***

```
@Entity
public class Review {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String message;
 
    @Convert(converter = RatingAttributeConverter.class)
    private Rating rating;
     
   //getters and setters
}
```

***PS : I tried using @Converter(autoApply=true) but it doesn't work neither.***
Please can someone help me find the solution

Comment: please any help mates

Comment: What type do you use for your table's column? Please provide the full stack trace. What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Look also at the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-enums). I guess you can use the `@Enumerated(ORDINAL)` for this purpose.